ansible task to use lxc exec to extract a tarball
I am trying to push a static website to an LXD Container. I could use lxc file push for every file, but I thought I'd push a single archive and then extract it.  I can run tar -xvf /home/ubuntu/public.tar.gz fine when I've logged into the container.  I can successfully push the archive, but the following ansible tasks fail to generate /home/ubuntu/public:
    - name: Push {{ app_dir }}/public.tar.gz to container
      ansible.builtin.shell:
        cmd: lxc file push {{app_dir}}/public.tar.gz {{ lxc_name }}{{ deploy_dir }}/public.tar.gz

    - name: Extract /home/ubuntu/public.tar.gz in container
      ansible.builtin.shell:
        cmd: lxc exec {{ lxc_name }} -- sh -c "tar -xvf /home/{{ lxc_user }}/public.tar.gz"



Connection plugin community.general.lxc  can take care of the container attach wrapper for you. Allowing containers to be hosts, and running modules on them.
The plugin requires python lxc bindings on the Ansible host.  I had a Fedora host, dnf install lxc{,-templates,-docs} python3-lxc
If unprivilaged user on the host is desired, see the idmap stuff in the getting started page  or this post about LXC on Fedora.
I picked a Debian container, you probably have Ubuntu given that home directory, basically same thing.  "cloud" variant as it has python3, useful for Ansible.
lxc-create --name debian --template download -- --dist debian --arch amd64  --variant cloud --release bookworm
lxc-start --name debian

Ansible inventory can reference containers by name. ini format example:
[lxc:vars]
ansible_connection=lxc
ansible_become_method=sudo

[lxc]
debian

Play:
---
- hosts: debian

  vars:
    app_user: ubuntu

  tasks:
    # User to match your example
    - become: true
      become_user: root
      user:
        name: "{{ app_user }}"
        state: present

    # unarchive module with a nice wrapper as we have python
    # Could instead use tar directly with raw module if no python
    - become: true
      become_user: "{{ app_user }}"
      unarchive:
        # With this option Ansible will take care of copying the archive into container
        remote_src: false
        # Where I stored the archive outside the container
        src: ~/ansible/1168042/public.tar.gz
        # assuming relative paths
        dest: ~{{ app_user }}



I understand lxc connection plugin will be root user in the container. If become commands are installed in the container, can switch to other users.
Similar to what you are doing with lxc exec this connection only works if the host running Ansible also is running the lxc container.
Note my play does not have to reference lxc commands. It can then be used unmodified with other types of hosts, say full VMs with a ssh connection.  Assuming the connection plugin is set correctly, ideally at the group level in inventory.
Containers as hosts allows Ansible features. Targeting of hosts and groups by name in plays. Group specific variables.

Thanks, I will give this a try.

I noticed the unarchived files at /root/public. After spending some time with the LXD documentation, I got the results I wanted with a couple more flags:
    - name: Extract /home/ubuntu/public.tar.gz in container
      ansible.builtin.shell:
        cmd: lxc exec {{ lxc_name }} --user 1000 --group 1000 --cwd /home/ubuntu -- sh -c "tar -xzvf public.tar.gz"

